# Mathematica setting that shows the notebook FPS in the titlebar

Tags: notebooks

There is a setting/preference that allows displaying the current frames per second (FPS) in the title bar. What setting is that?

[image: a screenshot showing the fps in the title bar]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CurrentValue[
  EvaluationNotebook[], {RenderingOptions, 
   "ShowFrameRateCounter"}] = True
```

This will set it for the current notebook.  You can set it against `$FrontEnd` or `$FrontEndSession` as well.

Manually, it can be set at 'Format>Option Inspector>Graphics Options>Rendering Options>ShowFrameRateCounter'